# Syntax Error in Update statement when updating

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2007

I am using this code 2 time on the same project and both tries worked, 
I'm wondering whats wrong on my code, my column and table is right (I copy pasted my names to be sure), and every time I try to update it, it always says syntax error on update statement

```
  string sql = "";
        sql = string.Format(@"UPDATE users_list
                                        SET Username='{0}',Last_name='{1}',Contact_number={2},Password='{3}',Position='{4}'
                                        WHERE ID={5}",

                                        txt_username.Text.Trim(),
                                        txt_userlastname.Text.Trim(),
                                        txt_usernumber.Text.Trim(),
                                        txt_userpassword.Text.Trim(),
                                        cbo_position.Text,
                                        txt_userid.Text.Trim());


        crudTools.ExecuteQuery(sql); //run the query
        MessageBox.Show("Records updated");
        Menu frm = new Menu();
        frm.Show(); //load form
        this.Hide(); //hide form
```

Comment: Print the "sql" after assigning query and copy paste the query string in access and check

Comment: Hard to know without seeing the tables and values, but is {2} missing ' around it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: @Dale_dale12 
Here is my column name and their data types
https://imgur.com/Fk3N5Pe

Comment: What is the value of `sql` when it fails?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to update "user_list" but in the screenshot you posted in the comments the table is called "users_table".

Change the SQL to reflect this and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: Already changed the table name after I noticed my name error, still getting the same error

Comment: Can you output the value of 'sql' and paste it here. It will be much easier to spot the error once all the replacements have been done